# How to get unix style prompt in windows (batch)

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file, unix

I am trying to make dos shell which displayes a unix/linux promt. The code is:

```
@echo off
:hi
set tmpdrv=%cd:~0,2%

if %homedrive% == %tmpdrv% (
  set drvmatch=1
) else (
  set drvmatch=0
)
set "MYSTRING=abcdef!%%^^()^!"
set MYSTRING=%homepath%
:strlen
(echo "%MYSTRING%" & echo.) | findstr /O . | more +1 | (set /P RESULT= & call exit /B %%RESULT%%)
set /A STRLENGTH=%ERRORLEVEL%-5
set tmppath1=%cd:~2%
CALL set tmppath2=%%tmppath1:~0,%STRLENGTH%%%
if %homepath% == %tmppath2% (
  set homematch=1
) else (
  set homematch=0
)

set homepathmatch=0
if %homepath% == %tmppath2% (
    if %homedrive% == %tmpdrv% (
    set homepathmatch=1
    )
)

if %homepathmatch%==1 (
    REM set /a STRLENGTH=%STRLENGTH%+2
        CALL set newpath=%%tmppath1:~%STRLENGTH%%%
    set newpath1=~%newpath%
)
set newpath2=%newpath1:\=/%
:check_Permissions

 net session >nul 2>&1
 if %errorLevel% == 0 (
 set "username2=root"
 ) else (
 set username2=%username%
 )
set /p %command%="%username2%@%computername%:%newpath2%$ "
%command%
goto :hi
```

I want it to display directory name like in unix/linux but it displays a `~`. What is wrong in my code? Can you please help me improve it?

Comment: The `PROMPT` command is used to make that setting.  I don't see you using it at all in your code.

Comment: Additionaly, when setting this variable: `set /p %command%="%username2%@%computername%:%newpath2%$ "`

you attempt to expand %command%, however command has not been defined - So your actually attempting to assign the string to an empty variable - which will always fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not quite on the ball with the prompts specific situational substring modification, but the Method of setting the Prompt is.

```
@ECHO OFF & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & TITLE %~n0
cls & MODE 1000 & CD %userprofile%\desktop


    For /F "tokens=* Delims=\" %%A In ("%userprofile%") Do (
        Set "C_Prompt=%%A"
        Set "C_Prompt=!C_Prompt:\=!"
        Set "C_Prompt=!C_Prompt:Users=!"
    For %%A in (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) Do (Set "C_Prompt=!C_Prompt:%%A:=!")
    )
    Set DirPath=:!CD:\=/!
    For %%A in (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) Do (Set "DirPath=!DirPath:%%A:=!")
    Set "C_Prompt=!C_Prompt!@!computername!!DirPath! $$ "

prompt !C_Prompt!

Start /B cmd.exe
```

The above does not refresh the command prompt with the working directory, however will result in commands behaving as expected without expansion issues.

[This linked Macro will refresh the Prompt when the working Directory changes, however the act of expanding commands within a user defined variable can result in unexpected results.](https://pastebin.com/Wc10yHnU)